# Ansible run commands with sudo but don't become root

Tags: ansible, root, sudo

I have a use case where I don't want the user executing the ansible commands to become root but I do want them to use sudo to do the commands.

probably not possible but i can't find anything that says one way or the other

Comment: if you don't want to become root, which other user are you becoming ? Did you simply try `become_user: toto` ? If [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) is correctly configured, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` allows you to specify which commands a given user or group of users is allowed to run as `root` .  For example, my `backuppc` account can only run two commands as `root`:

```
backuppc ALL=(root) /usr/bin/rsync,/sbin/e2label
```

Comment: `allowed to run as root` is quite reductive IMO. This is the most general used situation indeed but sudo allows to specify which commands a given user/group is allowed to run as any other user.